# How can I enable communication between ionic app and browser?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an app in ionic that can send message to browser in same device (android or ios) and receive response back from browser. Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of response are we talking about here? If you just want to create a request, you can look into `$http.get`, which can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) Otherwise please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve, perhaps you can share some examples of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I send a sms with link of my website. clicking on the link opens my website in bowser which redirects to appstore and playstore based on os of device. When the app is installed i intent to get token from the link i opened in browser. For that i need  communication between app and browser. I was previously doing this by getting token from the sms itself but i want know if there is any way for my app to communicate with browser to get that token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it is not possible to communicate with the native device browser to track which URL the user is visiting. However, using `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` you can open a browser window inside your application and track URL changes.

By listening to events, either `loadstart` or `loadstop` you can see where the user is and retrieve the URL with something like this:

```
var browserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

browserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
});
```

You can find more information on this plugin [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).